# Create docker containers using chef

Tags: docker, jenkins, chef-infra

I have a dockerfile to install jenkins and its dependencies in the container.
Can anyone suggest how should a dockerfile be build to create a docker image and create container of it? I have checked this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/chef/#requirements but that's no good as they are using docker image from docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

If the image will always exist locally then you can just skip the `docker_image` resource and use it directly. But this is unlikely to be the case if you have more than one server.

Comment: Hi coderanger,Thanks for the answer,but the requirement for my task is the user should be able to create docker image from the dockerfile and run a container of it.and this process should happen using chef scripts.